# OpenUI5/SAPUI5 how to make table rows with extra text

Tags: html-table, sapui5

I have a UI5 table, but would like to have an input element that span multiply rows under the other text. Something like the table below.

```
<table>
<tr><td>v1</td><td> v2</td><td> v3</td></tr><br>
<tr><td >input text </td></tr>
</table>
```

Comment: Are you using `sap.ui.table.Table` or `sap.m.Table`?

Comment: I'm using sap.m.Table

Comment: I'm not sure if it is possible. What is possible - is to remove all duplicate cell values in a row, leaving only the first one. This way you'll have a value in the first cell and other cells will be empty. Will it solve your problem?

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately, you'll have to find another approach. The `sap.m.Table` type does not currently support this, as there are no `span` type of properties on the [`sap.m.Column`](https://openui5.hana.ondemand.com/docs/api/symbols/sap.m.Column.html) type.

Answer (score 0):

Ok. Learned that it is not possible at the moment.

So I'm just going to use a textarea at the end of the line. I think it may look okay.

Answer (score 0):

Did you mean row span like [here](http://Did%20you%20mean%20row%20span%20(like%20[here][1]) or column span like [here](http://www.w3schools.com/tags/tryit.asp?filename=tryhtml_td_rowspan)

For rowspan there is existing sap.m.Column attribute [mergeDuplicates](https://openui5.hana.ondemand.com/docs/api/symbols/sap.m.Column.html#getMergeDuplicates) you may want to check.

Comment: It should be add an extra row and on this row have a span on. We just add the text at the end column